# How to limit the size of cache directory for s3ql?

Tags: s3ql

I mounted a remote S3 compatible filesystem with s3ql and provided a cache directory name. It works nicely, however, the cache directory uses more and more space on my local machine. Is there a way to limit the size of the content in the cache directory? I am now at 256GB. How can I limit it to e.g. 100GB?

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with the `--cachesize` option:

```
--cachesize 97656250  # for 100GB
```